# How to persist entity to two different tables using Spring+Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence

I imagine this pertains to Hibernate only (I'm just now beginning to use these two frameworks).  I have an application that tracks sessions for users.  While a session is active, the Session entity is stored in a table for active sessions.  When the user goes offline and the session ends, the session is moved to a secondary historical table.

How do I achieve this with Hibernate?  Right now I have a Session.hbm.xml file that maps a Session object to the active sessions table.  Can I map it to a secondary table and somehow specify to which table I want it to persist when I call saveOrUpdate?

**My reputation currently won't allow me to answer my own question this quickly.  I don't want anyone to waste their time on this though, since I found an answer, so I'm posting it here as an edit.**

I can do this by making use of the entity-name attribute in a mapping file.  I created a second mapping, identical to Session.hbm.xml, called HistoricalSession.hbm.xml.  In this new mapping file I reference the same Session class, but add:

```
entity-name="HistoricalSession"
```

Then I map the object to my second (historical) table just like normal.  Calling save() or saveOrUpdate() defaults to using the classname as the entity-name, and saves in my primary table as before.  Now, when I want to save a session to the historical table I use the Hibernate API overrides that allow you to specify an entity-name:

```
saveOrUpdate("HistoricalSession",session);
```

This accomplishes exactly what I want without need to create another Java class for historical sessions

Comment: I've thought of making a HistoricalSession entity with identical attributes to a Session but mapped to the historical table.  In this case I would create a HistoricalSession from a Session that I am closing, and then persist the HistoricalSession.  This will work, but requires creating a new object, a cost that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can do this by making use of the entity-name attribute in a mapping file.  I created a second mapping, identical to Session.hbm.xml, called HistoricalSession.hbm.xml.  In this new mapping file I reference the same Session class, but add:

```
entity-name="HistoricalSession"
```

Then I map the object to my second (historical) table just like normal.  Calling save() or saveOrUpdate() defaults to using the classname as the entity-name, and saves in my primary table as before.  Now, when I want to save a session to the historical table I use the Hibernate API overrides that allow you to specify an entity-name:

```
saveOrUpdate("HistoricalSession",session);
```

This accomplishes exactly what I want without need to create another Java class for historical sessions

Answer (score 1):

A couple of way to do this could be:

- Use a database trigger when the session gets expired the trrigger will move the row to the historical table.
- You can create a HistoricalSession extends Session and then do a second mapping for HistoricalSession and write the code to delete from Session and insert into historical session.

Answer (score 0):

Your need sounds like more of an audit like.
Check project [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) it might help solve your case in a better way.

Comment: I don't all the functionality ( and overhead ) of Envers.  I don't need a history of changes to the Object.  What I need is the Session object to be persisted to a different table, exactly as it would be persisted to the first table.  This will only ever happen once for a Session, and then the record will never be touched again.  When a session closes, it's moved to the historical table just so a GUI can show when users were online in the past etc etc.

Comment: Actually its not that overhead at all, thats your view point :). Its your app you choose whats best.....